# Memory Shared with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, memory, shared

I have a problem trying to link threads memory. I want that the counter shares the memory between threads that all of them only count to a certain number(100 in this case) and finally it is returned to the main thread. The problem is that even with lock all of the threads have a single count

```
import threading
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time
import multiprocessing
import random

def create_workers(n_threads, counter):
    # counter = 0
    workers = []
    for n in range(n_threads):
        worker = DataCampThread('Thread - ' + str(n), counter)
        workers.append(worker)

    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()

    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()

    return counter

def thread_delay(thread_name, num, delay):
    num += 1
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(thread_name, '-------->', num)
    return num

class DataCampThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, cou):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.counter = cou
        delay = random.randint(1, 2)
        self.delay = delay
        self.lock = Lock()

    def run(self):
        print('Starting Thread:', self.name)
        while self.counter < 100:
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.counter = thread_delay(self.name, self.counter, self.delay)
            self.lock.release()
        print('Execution of Thread:', self.name, 'is complete!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the agent
    n_threads = 3#multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    counter = 0
    create_workers(n_threads, counter)
    print(counter)
    print("Thread execution is complete!")
```

Comment: When I run the code currently in your question, all threads seem to have their own count and complete at different times—so it's unclear what the problem is. **Note** there's no reason to set the max value to 100, a much smaller value would be fine for debugging purposes.

Comment: It's also unclear why you're using a `Lock` since each `DataCampThread` has its own counter (so multiple threads would never be updating any shared memory).

Comment: The main idea is to have only one count, not to have different counts for each thread. I that each thread contribute to the main count asynchronous

Comment: In that case it sounds like you would want to have a global shared `count` value that each thread updated (after acquiring the lock for doing so). I'd try to show you how to do this, but I don't really understand everything that's going on. What exactly is the purpose/goal of defining your own `Thread` subclass (instead of just writing a function and passing it as an argument of the built-in `Thread` class)?

Comment: Also wonder why the `thread_delay()` function isn't a method of the class?

Comment: the problem is that I'm trying to program A3C and the variable that is normally shared between threads is not passed as a global variable. At least not in all the examples I have seen. That's why I want to have a variable that has the same values for all the threads without being a global variable, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I'm not really sure what you're trying to do — but here's an uninformed guess to (hopefully) expedite things.

Based on your response to the initial version of my answer about wanting to avoid a global variable, the counter is now a class attribute that will automatically be shared by all instances of the class. Each thread has its own name and randomly selected amount of time it delays between updates to the shared class attribute named `counter`.

**Note:** The test code redefines the `print()` function to prevent it from being used by more that one thread at a time.

```
import threading
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time
import random

MAXVAL = 10


class DataCampThread(Thread):

    counter = 0  # Class attribute.
    counter_lock = Lock()  # Control concurrent access to shared class attribute.

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()  # Initialize base class.
        self.name = name
        self.delay = random.randint(1, 2)

    def run(self):
        print('Starting Thread:', self.name)
        while True:
            with self.counter_lock:
                if self.counter >= MAXVAL:
                    break  # Exit while loop (also releases lock).
#                self.counter += 1  # DON'T USE - would create an instance-level attribute.
                type(self).counter += 1  # Update class attribute.
                print(self.name, '-------->', self.counter)
            time.sleep(self.delay)
        print('Execution of Thread:', self.name, 'is complete!')


def main(n_threads, maxval):
    ''' Create and start worker threads, then wait for them all to finish. '''

    workers = [DataCampThread(name=f'Thread #{i}')  for i in range(n_threads)]

    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()

    # Wait for all treads to finish.
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import builtins

    def print(*args, **kwargs):
        ''' Redefine print to prevent concurrent printing. '''
        with print.lock:
            builtins.print(*args, **kwargs)

    print.lock = Lock()  # Function attribute.

    n_threads = 3
    main(n_threads, MAXVAL)
    print()
    print('Thread execution is complete!')
    print('final counter value:', DataCampThread.counter)
```

Sample output:

```
Starting Thread: Thread #0
Starting Thread: Thread #1
Thread #0 --------> 1
Starting Thread: Thread #2
Thread #1 --------> 2
Thread #2 --------> 3
Thread #1 --------> 4
Thread #0 --------> 5
Thread #2 --------> 6
Thread #2 --------> 7
Thread #1 --------> 8
Thread #0 --------> 9
Thread #2 --------> 10
Execution of Thread: Thread #1 is complete!
Execution of Thread: Thread #0 is complete!
Execution of Thread: Thread #2 is complete!

Thread execution is complete!
final counter value: 10
```

Comment: thank you for the code, I understand a little bit better. Still, I would like to have a shared variable that is not global. I don't know if that is even possible.

Comment: Indeed, a shared non-global does sound a bit like an oxymoron. However, I think a workaround would be to use a class-level attribute which all instances can access — see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I wanted to do. One question, why do you use the function type() with the counter variable

Comment: Couple of reasons. 1.) So it updates the _class_ attribute. 2.) Avoids hardcoding the classname into the method's code (i.e. `DataCampThread.counter += 1`)—which means it will automatically continue working regardless of whatever the class is currently named.

Comment: Actually there's a (complicated) third reason. Using `self.counter += 1` instead would introduce a bug because it would have the side-effect of creating an instance-level attribute named `counter` which, from that point on, would hide the class-level one with the same name. This due to an arcane rule… _continued in next comment_

Comment: …regarding how [Augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) (like `+=`) work when used in conjunction with _attribute_ references because they're subject to [the same caveat about class and instance attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#attr-target-note) mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that is a really nice and clear explanation.