# How to prevent overprinting when using multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, printing, python-multithreading

I made my own script in python with multithreading.
The problem is my output is completely overprinted, and I need a clear output print.
In the picture below you can see the first 15 lines are fine, but after that its not good anymore.

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRiYi.png)

Comment: You can prevent it by redefining the `print()` function as shown near the end of the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66286326/355230) of mine to another threading question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Threads are printing at the same time messing up the text output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688424/python-threads-are-printing-at-the-same-time-messing-up-the-text-output)

Answer (score 0):

## Race conditions

You are most likely running into a *race condition* where the code is printing the first part of the line before the next part of the line.

### Example race

#### Problem code

```py
print(timestamp)
print(part of log)
print(rest of log)
```

#### Example result (with two threads)

T1: prints timestamp

T2: prints timestamp

T2: prints part of log

T1: prints part of log

T1: prints rest of log

T2: prints rest of log

#### Reason code fails

The prints can interleave, especially if you have a lot of threads running or it has an unexpected spike in data input.

#### Example code with fix

```py
log_string=f"{timestamp}{part of log}{rest of log}"
print(log_string)
```

#### Fix reason

If the print call happens all at once, it won't interleave the writes.

### See also

[What is a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34510/7818349)